# To communicate service-worker with Angular.js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, push-notification, service-worker

I'm implementing **Push Notifications** in my app. I made a service-worker to show the notification in my browser (Chrome).

Now, I need to call a function that it's inside an Angular Controller. I was trying to make an event like this in my service worker.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
 event.waitUntil(
  fetch(self.CONTENT_URL, {headers: headers})
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.status !== 200) {

    }
    return response.json().then(function(data) {

      /* some stuff*/

      document.dispatchEvent('myEvent');

      return notification;
    });
  })
 );
});
```

In this event I handle the notification and I'm trying to use an event.

In the controller I wrote the code below

```
document.addEventListener('myEvent', function(){
 console.log("im here");
});
```

But the browser doesn't show the console.log()

Any ideas to complete this task? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read docs for `dispatchEvent()`. You have no event object. Try simply running that event code in console will see the error thrown. Might want to use an angular event instead

Comment: Yes I want to use the angular event instead, but the service-worker is not an angular file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I did for communications between angular (or anything at the window/document side) with Service Worker

---

Somewhere in your angular app.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

  // ensure service worker is ready
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (reg) {

    // PING to service worker, later we will use this ping to identifies our client.
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage("ping");

    // listening for messages from service worker
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
      var messageFromSW = event.data;
      console.log("message from SW: " + messageFromSW);
      // you can also send a stringified JSON and then do a JSON.parse() here.
    });
  }
}
```

---

At the start of your service worker

```
let angularClient;
self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  // if message is a "ping" string, 
  // we store the client sent the message into angularClient variable
  if (event.data == "ping") { 
    angularClient = event.source;  
  }
});
```

---

When you receive a `push`

```
// In your push stuff
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
 event.waitUntil(
  fetch(self.CONTENT_URL, {headers: headers})
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.status !== 200) {

    }
    return response.json().then(function(data) {

      /* some stuff*/

      angularClient.postMessage('{"data": "you can send a stringified JSON here then parse it on the client"}');

      return notification;
    });
  })
 );
});
```

Comment: Nice one dude!!